# What is a Shifty Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property, seasonal

<sub>*In the spirit of the **What is a [Word™](/search?tab=Newest&q=is:question+%22I+call+it%22+title:Word%E2%84%A2)/[Phrase™](/search?tab=Newest&q=is:question+%22I+call+it%22+title:Phrase%E2%84%A2)** series started by [JLee](/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](/search?tab=Newest&q=is:question+phrase+title:%22What+is%22+title:Phrase+user:463) and [Word™](/search?tab=Newest&q=is:question+%22I+call+it%22+title:%22What+is%22+title:Word+user:463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Shifty Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Shifty Words™ | Not Shifty Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| BIKINI | SWIMWEAR |
| GABELLE | EXCISE |
| ACQUOPHONIA¹ | AUSCULTATION |
| ACOUOPHONIA | AEROPHOBIA |
| FOXIEST | SEXIEST |
| DULLEST | BRIGHTEST |
| GAZELLE | ANTELOPE |
| GENETIC | LEARNED |
| POLLSTER | VOTER |
| REDFISH | HERRING |
| LEOTARD² | LEGGINGS |

<sup>¹ This may not be a real word, but I did find it in various word lists. All other words are in UKACD18.

² ...</sup>

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Shifty Words™,Not Shifty Words™
BIKINI,SWIMWEAR
GABELLE,EXCISE
ACQUOPHONIA,AUSCULTATION
ACOUOPHONIA,AEROPHOBIA
FOXIEST,SEXIEST
DULLEST,BRIGHTEST
GAZELLE,ANTELOPE
GENETIC,LEARNED
POLLSTER,VOTER
REDFISH,HERRING
LEOTARD,LEGGINGS
```

This puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt rule that each word can be tested for whether it is a Shifty Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Shifty Words™; many more exist.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**
This particular list of Shifty Words™ is, of course, made up of words being shifty—**What are these Shifty Words™ hiding?**

_____
**Hint**

Here are a few extra words that *are* Shifty Words™:
  **BANDAGE COMPLEXION CURTAINS GRISLY OUTRANKED**
And a few extra words that are *Not* Shifty Words™:
  **BINDING CHEERED CURTAIN QUITE OUTRANGED**

These may help make the rule a little clearer.  (Or not.)

Comment: Your chosen adjective is really easy to misread :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Are you saying it was a shifty choice?

Answer (score 11):

Each Shifty Word can be changed to another word by shifting a letter two positions forward or back in the alphabet, wrapping around.

```
BIKINi -> BIKINg
GAbELLE -> GAzELLE 
ACqUOPHONIA -> ACoUOPHONIA
ACoUOPHONIA -> ACqUOPHONIA
FOxIEST -> FOzIEST
dULLEST -> fULLEST
GAzELLE -> GAbELLE
GENEtIC -> GENErIC
POLLsTER -> POLLuTER
REDfISH -> REDdISH
LEOtARD -> LEOpARD
```

If we take the letter that was jumped over (for example, changing I to G jumps over H), we can read off a message: HAPPY EASTER!

Edit: It looks like Shifty Words™ also require that there are no other one-letter changes that form a different word. For example, CURTAIN can become CURTAIL, but is not shifty because it can also have one letter changed to CERTAIN even though that's not a two-position shift.

LEOTARD instead shifts four positions to LEOpARD, of which we extract R as the midpoint, as hinted by its footnote.

Comment: Almost there now. You've put the cart before the horse.

Comment: rot13(YRBGNEQ (cyhf zbfg bs gur nqqrq Fuvsgl Jbeqf™) fubjf n gjb cbfvgvba fuvsg vf abg erdhverq. NREBCUBOVN (cyhf PURRERQ, PHEGNVA, naq DHVGR) fubjf n gjb cbfvgvba fuvsg vf abg fhssvpvrag. V guvax lbh'ir svtherq bhg jung'f tbvat ba, whfg arrq gb ersbezhyngr lbhe npghny ehyr. (Gur fcrpvsvp frnfbanyyl eryrinag jbeq yvfg va gur chmmyr vf n checbfrshyyl pubfra frg bs Fuvsgl Jbeqf™, ohg gurfr bs pbhefr zhfg or Fuvsgl Jbeqf™ svefg, naq gura "pbvapvqragnyyl" unccra gb unir gur pbairavragyl fvmrq fuvsg gung tvirf na rnfl gb fcbg zrffntr. Ohg gurl nyy, rira YRBGNEQ, fgvyy svg _bar ehyr_. Jung vf vg?))